# Third Party Library doesnt exists : error: package org.achartengine does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, achartengine

I am using org.achartengine in my Android Studio Project.I recently migrated it from the Eclipse.(imported).
I see the achartengine-1.1.0.jar under the assets folder but on building the apk I am getting this error :

Error:(30, 24) error: package org.achartengine does not exist

and hence errors at all those places where the functions from this library are referenced.

I am not getting any error If I do Tools>Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

WHat is the difference ?
How can I resolve this error?Perhaps some reference to library is not mentioned in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Move `achartengine-1.1.0.jar` to a new directory in `/your-project/app/libs`

Then add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to your dependencies section of your `build.gradle` file, like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Comment: Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'youProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
What is the gradle version you are using?